# SQL to join two views

Tags: sql, database, join, view

Need some help joining these two tables

I have two views that looks like this

```
view1                view2
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| code | SUM(*) |    | code | SUM(*) |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
| AAA  |      4 |    | AAA  |      4 |
| BBB  |      3 |    | CCC  |      1 |
+------+--------+    +------+--------+
```

I want to join them into a table that looks like this

```
+------+--------+
| code | SUM(*) |
+------+--------+
| AAA  |      4 |
| BBB  |      3 |
| CCC  |      1 |    
+------+--------+
```

I have tried, but only failed..

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe someone can determine why it failed. Looks to me like a `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what SQL you are trying and what the error or results are?

Also what database are you using?

Generally you can join VIEWS in the same manner you JOIN normal tables (so simple LEFT JOIN or UNION clauses).

Comment: Should `SUM(*)` in your result be 4 (as it is now) or 8 (adding the two values for `AAA` together)?

Comment: UNION was what I was looking for, I kept trying with different JOIN/DISTINCT clauses. @AdamRobinson it should not add the values.

Comment: I guess I should have made that an answer. :-p

Comment: @AdamRobinson, I was wrong! I want to add the AAA value. How can I do that?

Comment: @Wiseguy, you got an upvote :-)

Comment: @hakanito: If you want them added, see my answer. Also, please edit your question so that you're only asking one question (either you want the first result or the second result).

Comment: So...you *don't* want the query to add the values?

Comment: @AdamRobinson I needed both.. Sorry. Newbie in this forum :)

Comment: @hakanito: Then why did you accept an answer that didn't provide both...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first result, the answers posted using `union` will do the trick:

```
select * from view1
union
select * from view2
```

However, given the fact that one of your columns is a sum, this seems unlikely to be what you actually want.

For your second result (where the values are added), you'll need to use a `union` and a subquery:

```
select
    code,
    sum(yourcol)

from
(
    select
        code,
        yourcol

    from view1

    union all

    select
        code,
        yourcol

    from view2
) source

group by code
```

Answer (score 8):

```
select *
from view1
union
select *
from view2
```

Utilizing a `UNION` will not return duplicate entries, which is what it seems you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) for this:

```
SELECT * FROM view1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM view2
```